# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities :Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I am not familiar with LINQ and ive been trying to fix this by trying a
".ToList()" but i keep getting this same "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Here is my code:

```
internal IQueryable<ParameterlessTuple<tcDataCollectionConfiguration, tcDataCollectionConfiguration, tcDataCollectionConfiguration, tcDataCollectionConfiguration>> DataCollectionAcessQuery

        {

            get => (from conf in (from conf in this.Scope.Set<tcDataCollectionConfiguration>() where conf.DCC_ParameterName == "conf" select conf)

                    join yes in (from yes in this.Scope.Set<tcDataCollectionConfiguration>() where yes.DCC_ParameterName == "YesCode" select yes) on conf.DCC_StationID equals yes.DCC_StationID

                    join no in (from no in this.Scope.Set<tcDataCollectionConfiguration>() where no.DCC_ParameterName == "NoCode" select no) on conf.DCC_StationID equals no.DCC_StationID

                    join cancel in (from cancel in this.Scope.Set<tcDataCollectionConfiguration>() where cancel.DCC_ParameterName == "cancel" select cancel) on conf.DCC_StationID equals cancel.DCC_StationID

                    select new ParameterlessTuple<tcDataCollectionConfiguration, tcDataCollectionConfiguration, tcDataCollectionConfiguration, tcDataCollectionConfiguration>(conf, yes, no, cancel))

        }
```

Comment: [Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) ... [Tuple<T1,T2>(T1, T2) Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2.-ctor?view=net-5.0)

Comment: What is `ParameterlessTuple`? Why don't you use its parameterless constructor it seems to have seeing its name?

Comment: It does have that but i I get errors when I try to use it, this isn't my code base and I am not too familiar with C# / LINQ all I know for sure is that what I posted on my main post is what seems to be causing the error.